# MongoDB Performance Still Increased Even After Dropped an Index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection (800k docs) with some indexes. These days I found one of the query was very slow (10 seconds). I tried `db.my_collection.find({...}).explain()` and found it uses an index. I tried to created another index and re-exam my query. It ran very fast (0.01 seconds) but through `explain` I can see it still using that index (not using the new index I've just created).

Then I dropped the new index. It's strange to me that my query still very fast (0.01 seconds). Re-exam by `explain` it still using that index.

Does MongoDB somehow "remembered" my removed index? Or is there something happened inside MongoDB to track what I queried in memory even though after I dropped my index.

I'm new to MongoDB so any replies would be appreciate.

BTW, I'm using MongoDB Node.js Driver.

Comment: If the working set of the index needed to fill the query is large then there is a chance the query had not been paged in. However, I believe that case is unlikely since you noticed slowness before creating this new index. What MongoDB version is this?

Comment: @Sammaye I'm using 2.6.7